# How to call javascript function on the page load event of the child page which is in contentplaceholder?

Tags: javascript, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I've asp.net web site , i used master page for the design. I've many child pages which are placed in the contentplaceholder. I want to call the javascript function on the page load event of the child page. And there are different javascript functions on each child page.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating a

```
<script>
  (function yourFunc() {
  ....your code ....
  })();
</script>
```

in the child page and there you can use the function